# CKEditor disappears when I open Chrome Console

Tags: google-chrome, console, ckeditor

I use CKEditor for editing page content. It works perfectly, but when I open Google Chrome console, it removes all text and cursor caret inside editor.

After this I'm not able to focus editor.

Does anyone have same problem?

Comment: WFM. Chrome 36 on Mac.

Comment: Looks like some extensions causing this, because in incognito mode it works.

Comment: @zur4ik which one? Add as answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason of problem was chrome extension named: "Instant Translate".